# Freeze first column in horizontal scroll on lightning data table salesforce

Tags: lightning, lightning-datatable

I have created lightning datatable.

How to freeze first column only while scrolling horizontal (not vertical) in lightning datatable.( or css)

Source code :

```
<div class="slds-scrollable_y" style="height:100%;"> 
    <lightning:datatable columns="{!v.dataColumn}"
                                         data="{!v.lineItemData}"
                                         keyField="id"
                                         hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                                         class="slds-table slds-table_striped slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered"/></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please try using `<div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-fixed"` in your code

Comment: Thanks for reply. this one "slds-cell-fixed" fixed all cells now, i want just fixed first column in table. like this example (https://embed.plnkr.co/vZJuio/).

Answer (score 3):

It can be achieved by css:

```
<--!c:yourComponentStyle-->
.THIS table tr td:first-child {
    position:sticky;
    z-index: 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, if i used position fixed means vertical scroll is affected. i fixed this using position sticky.

Comment: It can be anything you want. The main idea here to write the correct css selector.

Comment: Yes got it  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue using position sticky.

in lightning datatable overflow property added for parent elements.

once remove those properties from class it will be working fine.

.THIS table tr td:first-child {
    position:sticky; top;0;
}

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to achieve the same thing as you. 
I used the position sticky but it's not working for me. You mentioned to remove the overflow property. Can you explain How?
In advance thank you